# Perform action after receiving push notification without user acknowledging

Tags: iphone

I'm quite sure the answer to this question is no but here it goes.

Is it possible to send a push notification to my app and have it perform some work without the user clicking on the push notification?

And even if it WERE possible, will my application be rejected because of this?

This question is from upper management, they want me to get our appication to be able to do this. I already told them that I don't believe it's possible but maybe someone knows something I don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method to to just what you want in Apple iOS 7 SDK, which unfortunately is under NDA at the moment so it's only allowed to discuss it inside Apple [Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/index.jspa), but you can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aperformFetchWithCompletionHandler%3a)